# Multiple inner-join statements combined with subquery

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Following query shows the results I need from table pointsList (latest records per user grouped by column idMatch)

```
select * from pointsList p
inner join ( select idMatch, max(datePointsCalculated ) as MaxDate from pointsList group by idMatch ) tm 
on p.idMatch = tm.idMatch and p.datePointsCalculated = tm.MaxDate 
order by p.idMatch ASC
```

But now I want to also select some additional information about the user (from table users). My naive way to tackle this was by making a new inner join like this:

```
select * from pointsList p, users u
inner join users
  on u.idUser = p.idUser
inner join ( select idMatch, max(datePointsCalculated ) as MaxDate from pointsList group by idMatch ) tm
  on p.idMatch = tm.idMatch and p.datePointsCalculated = tm.MaxDate
order by p.idMatch ASC
```

But I get the error message "unknown column 'p.idUser' in on clause". I tried using users.idUser and pointsList.idUser and other combinations (renaming pointsList in the on-clouse) but I always get the unknown column error (pointsList.idUser really does exist). Anyone could explain what I am doing wrong? I would like to extend this query to another table as well.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Comma `,` priority in FROM clause is less than JOIN priority. And your query acts as:

```sql
select * from pointsList p, 
                            (
                              users u
inner join users
  on u.idUser = p.idUser
inner join ( select idMatch, max(datePointsCalculated ) as MaxDate from pointsList group by idMatch ) tm
  on p.idMatch = tm.idMatch and p.datePointsCalculated = tm.MaxDate
                             )
order by p.idMatch ASC
```

Of course, table `pointsList AS p` is not accessible within the parenthesis.

Use CROSS JOIN instead of comma:

```sql
select * from pointsList p
CROSS JOIN users u
inner join users
  on u.idUser = p.idUser
inner join ( select idMatch, max(datePointsCalculated ) as MaxDate from pointsList group by idMatch ) tm
  on p.idMatch = tm.idMatch and p.datePointsCalculated = tm.MaxDate
order by p.idMatch ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. If I run the query as you propose, I get for each 'orginal' X records (from my first query) all records from the user table (Y records). So the result is X*Y records, they are not collapsed like I should expect with u.idUser = p.idUser. How could I fix that?

Comment: @H2SO4 If so then you need not CROSS JOIN but INNER JOIN with proper joining condition. Or maybe you simply add another copy of `users` table errorneously? *'select \* from pointsList p, **users** u inner join **users** ..'*

Comment: I removed CROSS JOIN from your query, and it seems to do the trick. Extended to another table 'matches' it looks like this 
`select * from pointsList p
inner join users u
  on u.idUser = p.idUser
inner join matches m
  on m.idMatch = p.idMatch
inner join ( select idMatch, max(datePointsCalculated ) as MaxDate from pointsList group by idMatch ) tm
  on p.idMatch = tm.idMatch and p.datePointsCalculated = tm.MaxDate
order by p.idMatch ASC`